# Replace FigureCanvasTkAgg content on repaeted button press in Tkinter

Tags: python-3.x, button, canvas, tkinter, configuration

I am stuck solving this problem. I have an analyse button that calls a function which creates a complex graph with matplotlib and puts it into a Frame on my tkinter GUI as a FigureCanvasTkAgg.
In the GUI the user should be able to press analyse again and run the analysis again and the existing Figure and Toolbar should be replaced by the new ones. With my code, the toolbars are piling up on every new button press and the figures also start stacking.

```
root = tk.ThemedTk()
analyse_button.place(x=70, y=350, anchor='w', height=30, width=210)

def analysis()
    ...
    f = Figure(figsize=(8, 5), dpi=125)
    a = f.add_subplot(111)
    graph = nx.Graph()
    ...

    frm = Frame(root, width=700, height=500)
    frm.place(x=240, y=420, anchor='w')

    canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(f, master=frm)
    canvas.draw()
    canvas.get_tk_widget().pack(side=TOP, fill=BOTH, expand=1)

    toolbar = NavigationToolbar2Tk(canvas, root)
    toolbar.configure(bg="white")
    toolbar.update()
    canvas._tkcanvas.pack()

...
root.mainloop()
```

I have tried to check if `frm` and `toolbar` already exist, in order to destroy them if they do, before the new ones are created.

```
if frm.winfo_exists():
    if toolbar.winfo_exists():
        frm.destroy()
        toolbar.destroy()
```

This of course gives me the error that `frm` and `toolbar` are not defined.

Any suggestions on how to approach this?

Answer (score 0):

You seem not to be aware what a local variable is. Also, your variables aren't declared at first. The simplest solution (although generally stupid) is to use sth. like this:

```
root = tk.ThemedTk()
analyse_button.place(x=70, y=350, anchor='w', height=30, width=210)

frm = None
toolbar = None

def analysis():
    global frm, toolbar
    if rfm is not None and frm.winfo_exists():
        if toolbar is not None and toolbar.winfo_exists():
            frm.destroy()
            toolbar.destroy()
    ...
    f = Figure(figsize=(8, 5), dpi=125)
    a = f.add_subplot(111)
    graph = nx.Graph()
    ...

    frm = Frame(root, width=700, height=500)
    frm.place(x=240, y=420, anchor='w')

    canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(f, master=frm)
    canvas.draw()
    canvas.get_tk_widget().pack(side=TOP, fill=BOTH, expand=1)

    toolbar = NavigationToolbar2Tk(canvas, root)
    toolbar.configure(bg="white")
    toolbar.update()
    canvas._tkcanvas.pack()

...
root.mainloop()
```

Using the `global` or `nonlocal` keywords is usually a bad practice, learn simple OOP principles to avoid it. Hope that's helpful!

Comment: Thanks, it helped. I am going to look into how to make this work more cleanly. My use of functions really does need improvement.